# Shredding XML from table column into a view in SQL Server

Tags: sql, xml, view, shred

I currently have this code which stores XML into an XML-type column called data, in a table called Storage.

```
    CREATE TABLE Storage
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    data XML NOT NULL
)

GO

INSERT INTO Storage(data) 
VALUES('<footballteams>   
    <team manager="Benitez">     
        <name>Liverpool</name>     
        <ground>Anfield</ground>   
    </team>   
    <team manager="Mourinho">     
        <name>Chelsea</name>     
        <ground>Stamford Bridge</ground>   
    </team>   
    <team manager="Wenger">     
         <name>Arsenal</name>     
         <ground>Highbury</ground>   
    </team> 
</footballteams>');
```

I would like to create a view called Football View which shreds the data and displays it in the form: FootballView(TeamName,Manager,Ground).

I have shredded full documents using the .nodes() method into table columns before, but it seems to be more challenging when creating a view (I have my reasons for using views). The problem is that previously I just called .nodes on a variable @input which was DECLARE'd as xml = 'xmlcontent' but with views this can't be done, and I want to parse XML contained within the Storage table column.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Previously, if I had shredded into tables this would be the code I use:

```
SELECT     
        TeamName = Foot.value('(name)[1]', 'varchar(100)'),     
        Manager = Foot.value('(@manager)', 'varchar(100)'),     
        Ground = Foot.value('(ground)[1]', 'varchar(100)')   
FROM     
        @input.nodes('/footballteams/team') AS Tbl(Foot)
```

EDIT2: This is the output I expect.

[image: Expected Output]

Comment: Can you post the code you used to shred into columns, and also how you've gone about trying to convert it.

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: What's the problem with placing that query in a view?

Comment: The problem is that previously I just called .nodes on a variable @input which was DECLARE'd as xml = 'xmlcontent' but with views this can't be done, and I want to parse XML contained within the Storage table column.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use `CROSS APPLY`

```
SELECT     
        TeamName = Foot.value('(name)[1]', 'varchar(100)'),     
        Manager = Foot.value('(@manager)', 'varchar(100)'),     
        Ground = Foot.value('(ground)[1]', 'varchar(100)')   
FROM    
    Storage S 
        CROSS APPLY data.nodes('/footballteams/team') AS Tbl(Foot)
```

`CROSS APPLY` and `OUTER APPLY` allow you to effectively join to a collection of XML in the current data set.

Comment: Can i ask, is the difference between cross and outer apply that outer will include NULLs too?

Comment: @user1320771 - [Using APPLY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) is a page on both forms, including the differences.